# scanf crops last byte of numbers

Tags: c, scanf

Take a look at this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned i = 0;
    char type = 'a';
    int result = scanf("%u%[asd]", &i, &type);
    printf("result = %d, i = %u\n", result, i);

    return 0;
}
```

It should accept a number then a character that is either `a`, `s` or `d`. When it gets an input where the second number is not matched, the number is parsed correctly and the return value is 1. If the input contains a correct character after the number, the return value is 2 and `type` is parsed correctly. However, the number has its last byte cropped (if I enter anything less than 256, I get 0, but if I enter for example 258 or 510, I still get 256). Why is this? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you read e.g. [this `scanf` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf), you will see that the `"%["` format is for reading a *string* which of course includes writing the string terminator character.

Since you only provide a single character to store the read string, the `scanf` function will *always* write out of bounds and you have [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

What happens is that the string terminator is written over part of the storage space for the variable `i`.

Answer (score 2):

```
int result = scanf("%u%[asd]", &i, &type);
```

The specifier `"%[...]"` is used to scan strings. You are interested in scanning a single char.

Either change `type` or change the specifier.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned i = 0;
    char type[20] = "a";         // changing type
    int result = scanf("%u%19[asd]", &i, type);
    printf("result = %d, i = %u\n", result, i);

    return 0;
}
```

---

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned i = 0;
    char type = 'a';
    int result = scanf("%u%c", &i, &type);        // changing specifier
    printf("result = %d, i = %u\n", result, i);

    return 0;
}
```